# using wildcards in expand-file-name in elisp?

Tags: emacs, filenames, glob, completion

Is it possible to use wildcards such as `*` in elisp to expand filenames?

For example, I saw that

```
(expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/elpa/babel-repl-20160504.1501")
```

expands to  `/home/username/.emacs.d/elpa/babel-repl-20160504.1501`.

Is there a function to also expand filenames containing wildcards so that we can do:

```
(expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/elpa/babel-repl*")
```

(taking the first filename if multiple matches exist)?

I tried the above, but `expand-file-name` does not seem to recognize `*` (Emacs 24.5 from Ubuntu 16.04)

-- EDIT --

@Drew I tried `(byte-recompile-directory (file-expand-wildcards "~/.emacs.d/elpa/babel-repl*/") 0)` but got an error `Wrong type argument: stringp, nil`.

I am not very familiar with elisp and the `stringp` type (a list of strings, I guess). I tried to use a `(car )` on the returned value of `file-expand-wildcards` in order to get the first matched filename. But Emacs still work start correctly.

Any pointers?

Comment: Your comment about using `(car )` did the trick! Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `file-expand-wildcards`:

> **`file-expand-wildcards`** is a compiled Lisp function in `files.el`.
>
> `(file-expand-wildcards PATTERN &optional FULL)`
>
> Expand wildcard pattern `PATTERN`.
>
> This returns a list of file names which match the pattern.
>
> If `PATTERN` is written as an absolute file name,
>   the values are absolute also.
>
> If `PATTERN` is written as a relative file name, it is interpreted
>   relative to the current default directory, `default-directory`.
>
> The file names returned are normally also relative to the current
>   default directory.  However, if `FULL` is non-nil, they are absolute.

That gives you a list of expansions.  Pick the first one or any one you want.